# Arduino 7 Segment code not running correct

Tags: arduino

I am trying to control a 4 digit SSEG display with an Arduino. When I press the button it should display a different number, however it currently just flashes the else statement. I also want the digit to be displayed on digit 1 not digit 3, I think theres something wrong with the input but not sure what.

```
int digit1 = 11; //PWM Display pin 1
int digit2 = 10; //PWM Display pin 2
int digit3 = 9; //PWM Display pin 6
int digit4 = 6; //PWM Display pin 8
//Pin mapping from Arduino to the ATmega DIP28
//http://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping
int segA = A1; //Display pin 14
int segB = 3; //Display pin 16
int segC = 4; //Display pin 13
int segD = 5; //Display pin 3
int segE = A0; //Display pin 5
int segF = 7; //Display pin 11
int segG = 8; //Display pin 15
int button1 = 13; //input
int val = 0;
void setup() {                
  pinMode(segA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(segB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(segC, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(segD, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(segE, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(segF, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(segG, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(digit1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(digit2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(digit3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(digit4, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(button1, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  #define DIGIT_ON  HIGH
  #define DIGIT_OFF  LOW
  #define SEGMENT_ON  LOW
  #define SEGMENT_OFF HIGH

  clearLEDs();
  button();
}

void clearLEDs(){  
  digitalWrite(digit1, DIGIT_OFF);
  digitalWrite(digit2, DIGIT_OFF);
  digitalWrite(digit3, DIGIT_OFF);
  digitalWrite(digit4, DIGIT_OFF);
  digitalWrite(segA, SEGMENT_OFF); // A
  digitalWrite(segB, SEGMENT_OFF); // B
  digitalWrite(segC, SEGMENT_OFF); // C
  digitalWrite(segD, SEGMENT_OFF); // D
  digitalWrite(segE, SEGMENT_OFF); // E
  digitalWrite(segF, SEGMENT_OFF); // F
  digitalWrite(segG, SEGMENT_OFF); // G 
  delay(100);
}  
  void button(){
    val = digitalRead(button1);
    if(button1 == HIGH){
    digitalWrite(digit1, DIGIT_ON);  
    digitalWrite(segA, SEGMENT_OFF);
    digitalWrite(segB, SEGMENT_ON);
    digitalWrite(segC, SEGMENT_ON);
    digitalWrite(segD, SEGMENT_OFF);
    digitalWrite(segE, SEGMENT_OFF);
    digitalWrite(segF, SEGMENT_OFF);
    digitalWrite(segG, SEGMENT_OFF);
    delay(400);
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(digit3, DIGIT_ON);
    digitalWrite(segA, SEGMENT_ON);
    digitalWrite(segB, SEGMENT_ON);
    digitalWrite(segC, SEGMENT_OFF);
    digitalWrite(segD, SEGMENT_ON);
    digitalWrite(segE, SEGMENT_ON);
    digitalWrite(segF, SEGMENT_OFF);
    digitalWrite(segG, SEGMENT_ON);
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be switching your logic on the edges of the button press rather than just reading the current state. The problem is that the button will be `LOW` the whole time apart from the few milliseonds that you are actively pressing it. [Here](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ButtonStateChange) is an example of implementing some edge detection.